# Is it possible to use axios.all with a then() for each promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I have a React component that triggers an event to fetch data.  This results in a dynamic number of stored proc calls to fetch data, and the data from each call is stored in a totally different location.  Then I need to re-render once all of the data is received and available.  I'm using promises with axios.

Since the number of axios calls is dynamic, I'm building an array and inserting it into `axios.all` as follows:

```
let promises = [];

for (let i = 0; i < requests.length; i++) {
    promises.push(axios.get(request[i].url, { params: {...} }));
}

axios.all(promises).then(/* use the data */);
```

The problem is that each axios request returns data that gets added to an object in a totally different place.  Since I have no way to put them all in the correct place in a single `then` (how would I know which response goes in which location?), I tried doing something like this:

```
let promises = [];

for (let i = 0; i < requests.length; i++) {
    promises.push(
        axios.get(request[i].url, { params: {...} })
            .then(response => {myObject[request[i].saveLocation] = response.data;})
    );
}

axios.all(promises).then(/* use the data */);
```

However, this doesn't work as I expected.  The `then` after each `get` is executed, but not until well after the `then` attached to `axios.all`.  Obviously this is a problem because my code tries to use the data before it has been saved to the object.

Is there a way to have a separate `then` call for each `axios.get` that will be executed after its corresponding promise is resolved, and then have a final `then` that will be executed only after *all* of the promises are resolved, to use the data now that the object has been populated?

Comment: "*how would I know which response goes in which location?*" - [they come out in the same order as they were passed in](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28066429/1048572)

Comment: I don't see any reason why this code does not work. What exactly does `/* use the data */` look like?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Okay, so I found a way to do what I needed without using using a `then` on each `get`.  Since the params passed in to `axios.get` contain enough info to determine the save location, and since I can read the params back from the response, I can do something like the following:

```
let promises = [];

for (let i = 0; i < requests.length; i++) {
    promises.push(axios.get(request[i].url, { params: {...} }));
}

axios.all(promises)
    .then(axios.spread((...args) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            myObject[args[i].config.params.saveLocation] = args[i].data;
        }
    }))
    .then(/* use the data */);
```

This ensures all the data is received and saved to the object before it is used.

Answer (score 3):

If the behaviour of your second attempt is indeed like that, then that would be an indication that `axios` is not Promise/A+ compliant. The `then` callback's return value must be the value with which the promise returned by that `then` is fulfilled. Since that is the promise you push into the array, the value that `axios.all` would return for that promise can only be known by executing the `then` callbacks first.

Even though you do not return a value explicitly in the `then` callback, this does not affect the above rule: in that case the return value is `undefined` and it is *that* value that should be provided by `axios.all` once the corresponding promise is resolved.

See in particular the rules 2.2.7, 2.2.7.1, 2.3.2.1, 2.3.2.2 [in the specs of Promise/A+](https://promisesaplus.com):

> 2.2.7 `then` must return a promise.
>
> ```
> promise2 = promise1.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
> ```
>
> 2.2.7.1 If either `onFulfilled` or `onRejected` returns a value `x`, run the Promise Resolution Procedure `[[Resolve]](promise2, x)`.
>
> [...]
>
> To run `[[Resolve]](promise, x)`, perform the following steps:
>
> [...]
>
> 2.3.2 If `x` is a promise, adopt its state:
>
> 2.3.2.1 If `x` is pending, `promise` must remain pending until `x` is fulfilled or rejected.
>
> 2.3.2.2 If/when `x` is fulfilled, fulfill `promise` with the same value.

So I would suggest using a Promise/A+ compliant promise implementation instead. There are several other libraries, like for instance [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise).

Alternatively, you could use the native ES6 Promise implementation, and [promisify the `http.request` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38533580/nodejs-how-to-promisify-http-request-reject-got-called-two-times) yourself.

ES6 offers `Promise.all` which guarantees to provide the resolved values in the same order as the promises were provided.

Comment: Interesting.  I found a way around having a `then` after each `get`, but I appreciate your response.  Now it seems even more strange that axios behaves as it does.

Answer (score 2):

It seems at this post day, axios recommends using Promise.all instead of axios.all
https://github.com/axios/axios
this is what worked for me, with Nuxtjs

```
async nuxtServerInit(vuexContext, context) {
    console.log(context);

    const primaryMenuData = {
      query: `query GET_MENU($id: ID!) {
        menu(id: $id, idType: NAME) {
          count
          id
          databaseId
          slug
          name
          menuItems {
            edges {
              node {
                url
                label
                target
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }`,
      variables: {
        "id": "Primary"
      }
    }

    const primaryMenuOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
      data: primaryMenuData,
      url: 'http://localhost/graphql'
    };

    const postsData = {
      query: `query GET_POSTS($first: Int) {
        posts(first: $first) {
          edges {
            node {
              postId
              title
              date
              excerpt
              slug
              author {
                node {
                  name
                }
              }
              featuredImage {
                node {
                  altText
                  caption
                  sourceUrl(size: MEDIUM)
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }`,
      variables: {
        "first": 15
      }
    }

    const postsOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
      data: postsData,
      url: 'http://localhost/graphql'
    };
        
    try {
      const [primaryMenuResponse, postsResponse] = await Promise.all([
        await axios(primaryMenuOptions),
        await axios(postsOptions)
      ])
      
      vuexContext.commit('setPrimaryMenu', primaryMenuResponse.data.data.menu.menuItems.edges);
      vuexContext.commit('setPosts', postsResponse.data.data.posts.edges);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }      
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

your initial code could work normally as intended if you pass the promises to your array attached with their respective `then` function

```
let promises = []; // array to hold all requests promises with their then
for (let i = 0; i < requests.length; i++) {
    // adding every request to the array
    promises.push(
        axios.get(request[i].url, { params: { ...} })
            .then(response => { myObject[request[i].saveLocation] = response.data; })
    );
}
// Resolving requests with their callbacks before procedding to the last then callback
axios.all(promises).then(/* use the data */);
```

Comment: Your code block is essentially identical to the code block in the question. Just the comments and spacing are different.

Comment: exactly , i just wanted to add comments to his code to show him when the promise is run.