# Why I getting the last promise?

Tags: node.js, https, promise, axios

I am trying handle all promise.But i getting only the last promise? I looked npm axios module.Code is run in that:

```
 axios.all([f1(), f2()]).then(axios.spread(function(res1, res2) { //handle }));
```

I create new array named powerPlants for hold promise functions:

```
  const powerPlants = meters.map( meter => {
     const obj = {};
     params.meter = meter; //  changing parameter for post request
     obj[meter] = function(){
        return axios.post('https://power.ivyiot.com/Thingworx/Things/GamaNetworkServices/Services/GetHistoricDataByMinute',params,options);
     };    
    return obj[meter]();           });
```

and i want to handle all promise seperately as below.But is not working.

```
 axios.all(powerPlants).then(axios.spread((a,b,c,d,e,f,g)=>{
        console.log(a); //meter parameter of a should be powertTrack2001 but it powerTrack2007 
}))
```

Comment: WTH are that `obj` and the `obj[meter]` method good for? Why not just call and return `axios.post()` directly?

Comment: What exactly is the result that you are getting and how does it differ from the expected one?

Comment: Where is `params` declared? You constantly mutate it during your loop.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664566/is-it-possible-to-use-axios-all-with-a-then-for-each-promise

Comment: I editted my question. @Bergi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only a single `params` object whose `.meter` property you are changing - it ends up with the last assigned value. Given that this object is part of your promise result, it's the same everywhere. Make a copy of your `params` to avoid this:

```
axios.all(meters.map(meter => {
    const paramObj = Object.assign({}, params, {meter});
    return axios.post('https://power.ivyiot.com/Thingworx/Things/GamaNetworkServices/Services/GetHistoricDataByMinute', paramObj, options);
})).then(…)
```