# Invoking an api inside a aws lambda but getting a null response

Tags: javascript, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to invoke a rest API inside an API but it is not returning anything. So I am making a simple lambda which returns a JSON but getting a null value as a response.

```
var https = require('https');
var dt;
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
      var data = '';

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var params = {
                host: "cvwtzygw4a.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com",
                path: "/test/first"
                };

        const req = https.request(params, (res) => {
          console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
           res.setEncoding('utf8');
           res.o n('data', function(chunk) {
               data += chunk;
             });
         res.on('end', function() {
          console.log("DONE");

          console.log(data);
           dt = JSON.parse(data);
          console.log(dt);
         });


      resolve(dt);
    });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
      reject(e.message);
    });

    // send the request
    req.write('');
    req.end();
 });
};
```

Comment: `resolve(dt)` will not wait for async calls.

Comment: you can use [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) for invoking API's

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nodejs - How to promisify http.request? reject got called two times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38533580/nodejs-how-to-promisify-http-request-reject-got-called-two-times)

Comment: i am new to async programming can you provide the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go through [this article](https://sarthakj178.com/handling-nodejs-promises-in-aws-lambda/) to understand how to use NodeJs promises in AWS Lambda. In this, the [second solution](https://sarthakj178.com/handling-nodejs-promises-in-aws-lambda/#solution-async-await) addresses your use case.

To be specific to your code, I modified to make it very simple using the async/await syntax and the request-promise library.

```
const request = require('request-promise');
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    var data = '';

    try {
        data = await request.get('https://cvwtzygw4a.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/test/first');
        console.log('response received', res);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error', error);
    }
    return data;
};
```

Following was the output:

```
START RequestId: 80d75f93-5fa6-1354-c22c-0597beb075e7 Version: $LATEST
2020-01-03T17:51:19.987Z        80d75f93-5fa6-1354-c22c-0597beb075e7    response received {
"basic" : {"name":"John","age":31,"city":"New York"}
}
END RequestId: 80d75f93-5fa6-1354-c22c-0597beb075e7
REPORT RequestId: 80d75f93-5fa6-1354-c22c-0597beb075e7  Init Duration: 907.81 ms        Duration: 1258.54 ms    Billed Duration: 1300 ms        Memory Size: 128 MB       Max Memory Used: 55 MB

"{\n\"basic\" : {\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":31,\"city\":\"New York\"}\n}"
```