# Web scraping different websites and pushing values to object

Tags: javascript, request, cheerio

I'm trying to loop through different websites and scrape their values and push it to a global variable. I've tried different things but I seem unable to push val to dat. My goal is to have an object with the stock values of DAL and AAL.

```
var request = require("request"),
cheerio = require("cheerio");

var ticker = ["DAL", "AAL"];
var dat = []

for (var i = 0; i < ticker.length; i++) {
  var url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+ ticker[i] + "?p=" + ticker[i];
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        var val = {
          Ticker : ticker[i],
          "Date" : new Date(),
          PreviousClose : $("span[data-reactid='98']").text().toString(),
          Open : $("span[data-reactid='103']").text().toString(),
          Bid : $("span[data-reactid='108']").text().toString(),
          Ask : $("span[data-reactid='113']").text().toString(),
          DayRange : $("td[data-reactid='117']").text().toString(),
          WeekRange_52 : $("td[data-reactid='121']").text().toString(),
          Volume : $("span[data-reactid='126']").text().toString(),
          AverageVolume : $("span[data-reactid='131']").text().toString(),
          MarketCap : $("span[data-reactid='139']").text().toString(),
          Beta5Months : $("span[data-reactid='144']").text().toString(),
          PEratio : $("span[data-reactid='149']").text().toString(),
          "EPS" : $("span[data-reactid='154']").text().toString()
        };
      } else {
        return console.error(error);
      }
    });
    dat.push(val);
}

console.log(dat);
```

Comment: Easier to use an api if all you are wanting is stock ticker data

Comment: Those data-react-id's are going to change the next time they bundle that thing. The data is on the page as JSON and you should use that.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

```js
var request = require("request"),
cheerio = require("cheerio");

var ticker = ["DAL", "AAL"];
var dat = []

for (var i = 0; i < ticker.length; i++) {
  var url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+ ticker[i] + "?p=" + ticker[i];
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        var val = {
          Ticker : ticker[i],
          "Date" : new Date(),
          PreviousClose : $("span[data-reactid='98']").text().toString(),
          Open : $("span[data-reactid='103']").text().toString(),
          Bid : $("span[data-reactid='108']").text().toString(),
          Ask : $("span[data-reactid='113']").text().toString(),
          DayRange : $("td[data-reactid='117']").text().toString(),
          WeekRange_52 : $("td[data-reactid='121']").text().toString(),
          Volume : $("span[data-reactid='126']").text().toString(),
          AverageVolume : $("span[data-reactid='131']").text().toString(),
          MarketCap : $("span[data-reactid='139']").text().toString(),
          Beta5Months : $("span[data-reactid='144']").text().toString(),
          PEratio : $("span[data-reactid='149']").text().toString(),
          "EPS" : $("span[data-reactid='154']").text().toString()
        }; 
        dat.push(val); // moved the push call to inside this if statement so it's in the same "scope" as the var variable
      } else {
        console.error(error);
      }
    });
}

console.log(dat);
```

ORIGINAL:

The problem is `val` is being limited to the scope of the `if` statement you create it in. (Read more about it [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript))

Try adding `var val;` above the `request` call (assuming `request` is a synchronous function, read more about asynchronous vs. synchronous [here](https://dev.to/hardy613/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-programming-23ed)).

So it'd look something like this:

```js
// .... keep the code up here
  var url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+ ticker[i] + "?p=" + ticker[I];
    var val;
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        val = {
// ... keep your code from down here
```

Basically the `val` variable is essentially "destroyed" (to put it simply) after that `if` statement completes, so `dat.push` doesn't have access to it.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I more or less understand the problem, but since I'm new to Javascript I'm unable to solve it.

Comment: What do you want the output to be? Do you have a link to the code? I just need to know what the output should look like.

Comment: For each iteration of the loop I want to push the values obtained from scraping the website into the initiated global variable dat. When calling dat outside the function it should contain: [{Ticker : "DAAL", Date : value, etc. }, {Ticker : "AAL, Date: value} ]

Comment: I just edited your original code. That should work for you.

Comment: I tried the edited code and again it didn't work. I believe it has to do with the function call in the code, where val only exists within this function scope, but I tried just about anything I could think of and still not able to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The code could be improved by running the [requests concurrently using promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38533580/nodejs-how-to-promisify-http-request-reject-got-called-two-times/38543075#38543075), but to answer the question as asked, do the work of pushing `val` inside the callback where it is defined (the OP placement of that line won't parse).  Similarly, there's no point in logging the accumulated data until the last callback invocation.

```
for (var i = 0; i < ticker.length; i++) {
  var url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+ ticker[i] + "?p=" + ticker[i];
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        var val = {
          Ticker : ticker[i],
          "Date" : new Date(),
          PreviousClose : $("span[data-reactid='98']").text().toString(),
          Open : $("span[data-reactid='103']").text().toString(),
          Bid : $("span[data-reactid='108']").text().toString(),
          Ask : $("span[data-reactid='113']").text().toString(),
          DayRange : $("td[data-reactid='117']").text().toString(),
          WeekRange_52 : $("td[data-reactid='121']").text().toString(),
          Volume : $("span[data-reactid='126']").text().toString(),
          AverageVolume : $("span[data-reactid='131']").text().toString(),
          MarketCap : $("span[data-reactid='139']").text().toString(),
          Beta5Months : $("span[data-reactid='144']").text().toString(),
          PEratio : $("span[data-reactid='149']").text().toString(),
          "EPS" : $("span[data-reactid='154']").text().toString()
        };
        // relocated OP cumulating and logging code here:
        dat.push(val);
        if (i === ticker.length-1) {
          console.log(dat);
        }
      } else {
        return console.error(error);
      }
    });
}
```