# Async function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have an async function that is returning undefined when I console.log the response. The code that calls the function is inside a Lambda function that is async itself hence the desire to use `await`. The sendRequest function is outside that lambda function though is in the same file.

```
// main.js
async sendRequest ...

exports.foobar = async ...
```

Below is the code that calls the function (which is inside another function).

```
const response = await sendRequest(url)
console.log(response)
```

sendRequest async function that returns undefined

```
async function sendRequest (url) {
  let code;
  request({ url, timeout: 20000 }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error == 'ENOTFOUND' || error == 'ETIMEDOUT') {
      response.statusCode = 500;
    }
    code = response.statusCode
    return {
      code, 
      error
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: code variable is never filled, it always be undefined

Comment: @mgm793 See that I stripped it out by accident when posting. I will edit, though I'd still expect to get an object back so I don't think the missing thing in code is the issue.

Comment: There's a general purpose "promisified" http request here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38543075/294949

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return a `Promise` from `sendRequest`. `request` is taking a callback, but that won't work with async-await. The general pattern looks like this

```
function sendRequest(...) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // resolve(...) or reject(...);
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks so can I leave the callback with request, I don't think it supports promises which is why I was trying to use callback here.

Comment: @joshk132 correct you have to adapt it to use promises instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer to the question not a guess based off a comment and saying duplicate like someone else has done. Much apperciated