# What are different ways to handle asynchronous calls (apis) inside a for loop or array method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have been trying to create an api like this where I tried different things like using array methods like map/filter/reduce where either I get pending promises or result returned before execution of api call.
So my doubt is -->

- How do I get total number of drawn matches of all pages ( so I need to add data.total from all pages).
- How to better understand this behaviour.

```js
async function getNumDraws(year) {
    const goals = [...Array(11).keys()];
    let result = 0;

    console.log(`before loop ${new Date()}`);
    for(let goal of goals){
        console.log(`in loop before await ${new Date()}`);
        await require('https').get(`https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/football_matches?year=${year}&team1goals=${goal}&team2goals=${goal}`,res=>{
            let data="";
            res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data += chunk;
            });
            // The whole res has been received. Print out the result.
            res.on('end', () => {
                data=JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(result,data.total)
                result= result + data.total;
            });
        })
        console.log(`in loop after await ${new Date()}`);

    }
    console.log(`after loop ${new Date()}`);
    return result;

}
console.log(getNumDraws(2011));
```

Comment: To make a bunch of API calls, use `Promise.all()` and pass an array of promises to it. At the end, send back the array using `res.json()`.

Answer (score 4):

`https.get` is a callbacked function so `await` won't work. You should promisify it first like they did in this [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38533580/9867451);

```
const https = require("https");                                      // only require this once

const getJSONAsync = url => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {       // define a function getJSONAsync which returns a Promise that wraps the https.get call, getJSONAsync is awaitable
  let req = https.get(url, res => {                                  // make the https.get request
    if(res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode >= 300) {              // if the status code is an error one
      return reject(new Error('statusCode=' + res.statusCode));      // reject and skip the rest
    }

    let body = [];                                                   // otherwise accumulate..
    res.on('data', chunk => body.push(chunk));                       // ..the data
    res.on('end', () => {                                            // on end                               
      try {
        body = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(body).toString());           // try to JSON.parse the data
      } catch(e) {
        reject(e);                                                   // reject if an error occurs
      }
      resolve(body);                                                 // resolve the parsed json object otherwise
    });
  });

  req.on("error", error => reject(error));                           // reject if the request fails too (if something went wrong before the request is sent for example)
});

async function getNumDraws(year) {
  let result = 0;

  for(let goal = 0; goal < 11; goal++) {
    let data = await getJSONAsync(`https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/football_matches?year=${year}&team1goals=${goal}&team2goals=${goal}`);
    result += data.total;
  }

  return result;
}
```

**Note:** `getJSONAsync` is not specific to `getNumDraws`, you can use it somewhere else if you need it, and since it returns a `Promise` you can either `await` it like `getNumDraws` does or use it with `then`/`catch` blocks like so:

```
getJSONAsync("url")
  .then(data => {
    // data is the parsed json returned by the request
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // the error message if something fails
  })
```