# Http Request not being ran unsure what the issue is

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Been debugging all night, but I can't figure out why my http request is not being called

```
return getWordDefinition(queryUrl).then(function(responseMsg) {
    //Perform some other business logic
},
  function(err) {
      console.log('Error Getting Definition: ' + err);
});
```

The function I'm trying to call:

```
function getWordDefinition(queryUrl){
    
    const options = {
    method: "GET"
  };

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        const request = https.request(queryUrl, options, function(response) {

        console.log("STATUS CODE: " + response.statusCode);  // <------Not being called

        var data;
        response.on("data", function(chunk) {
          if (!data) {
            data = chunk;
          } else {
            data += chunk;
          }
        });
    
        response.on("end", function() {
          console.log("Data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
          resolve("Finished getting data");
        });
        
        request.on('error', (e) => {
          reject("ERROR ON REQUEST: " + e.message);
        });
        
        request.end();
        
      });
    });
  
}
```

This code is inside my `AWS lambda function` which seems to be timing out.
I'm logging the status code for the http request, but it's never being called in my function.
What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Lambda is making an HTTP request and it appears to be timing out?

Here are 3 possible reasons, in descending order of likelihood:

1. it's running in VPC and you've given the Lambda no route to the internet
2. the HTTP request takes longer than the Lambda timeout (default is 3 seconds)
3. your async/promise code has a bug

See [Internet and service access for VPC-connected functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html#vpc-internet) for #1.

Comment: It says "No VPC configuration" under my lambda function, also I've tried changing the time out to 1 min, but it's still timing out. The request to the endpoint takes 1 second in the address bar

Comment: I've also tried attaching ```AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole``` instead of ```AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole``` in my policies for that lambda function

Comment: Run the same HTTPS request code on your laptop. Does it work?

Comment: no, I don't think it's a lambda issue. The ```return new Promise(function . . .``` status code  log is still not called. So I think I'm making the request incorrectly

Comment: See [wrapping https.request in promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38533580/nodejs-how-to-promisify-http-request-reject-got-called-two-times) or switch to something promise-native like Axios (also has nicer interface).

Comment: Thanks for helping me debug the issue and also recommending axios...so much better than using https.request, Once I switched I got it done in 3 lines with no issues.