# How do i get data from multiple apis simultanously and display them on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, web-deployment

I am building a news/blog website which gets the data from an external api and displays it to the webpage.So far I have managed to render data from one api but I also have a sport section in my  webpage which requires me to get data from another such api but i dont know how i can do that without node throwing me an error.
Below is my NODE.JS code-

```
//jshint esversion: 6

const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
const sporturl ="https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/feeds/newsfeed/33187923.cms? 
feedtype=sjson";
const newsurl = "https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/feeds/newsdefaultfeeds.cms? 
feedtype=sjson#";
https.get(newsurl, function(response){
    var data;
response.on("data", function(chunk) {
    if (!data) {
        data = chunk;
    } else {
        data += chunk;
    }
});

response.on("end", function() {
    const fulldata = JSON.parse(data);
            let mainHeader = fulldata.NewsItem[0].HeadLine;
            let mainheaderurl = fulldata.NewsItem[0].WebURL;
            let mainCaption = fulldata.NewsItem[0].Caption;
            let mainUrl = fulldata.NewsItem[0].Image.Photo;
            let featured = fulldata.NewsItem[1].HeadLine;
            let featuredlink = fulldata.NewsItem[1].WebURL;
            let featuredimg = fulldata.NewsItem[1].Image.Photo;


    res.render("index",{
                mainHeader: mainHeader,
                headerUrl: mainheaderurl,
                mainCaption: mainCaption,
                imgUrl: mainUrl,
                featured:featured,
                featuredlink:featuredlink,
                featuredimg:featuredimg,
            });
     });

     });
  
     });

     app.listen(port, () => {
     console.log(`server started on port 3000`);
     });
    // api key: ff827a803d4540f5814864d207fd23b5
    // const mainHeadingUrl = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=tesla&from=2021- 
    05-26&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=ff827a803d4540f5814864d207fd23b5";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) (for nodeJS you could utilise [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)), [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await), and [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to gather the data.

Push some API calls into an array. They will return as promises (a promise that data will (or will not) return). `Promise.all` waits until *all* those promises have *resolved*, and outputs the data as an array that you can then iterate over.

```js
function mockApi(n) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(n), 2000);
  });
}

// Here you would bundle up your fetch calls
// eg:  fetch(url)
// I'm using mockApi as a convenience
const fetchCalls = [mockApi(1), mockApi(2), mockApi(3)];

async function getData() {
  const data = await Promise.all(fetchCalls);
  console.log(data);
}

getData();
```

Comment: When i did that it gave me an error saying fetch is not defined

Comment: Ah. You could use [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) or, as  Prakash S mentions, promisify https.

Comment: i got that error off but now when logged the data it just says the url back

Answer (score 0):

This is answered here.

[nodejs - How to promisify http.request? reject got called two times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38533580/nodejs-how-to-promisify-http-request-reject-got-called-two-times)

You can then use the method described there and use Promise.all and achieve the desired result