# nodejs loop curl, async or blocking

Tags: node.js

how to loop curl/request when each request is done? like php/blocking.
its currently using loop foreach **async-foreach** and **request**.

my code:

```
forEach(array_lines, function(page_url, index, arr) {
        request(page_url, function (err, resp, body) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error!: " + err + " using ("+j+")" + page_url);
            throw err;
        }
        var $ = cheerio.load(body,{ decodeEntities: false,xmlMode: true });

        console.log('page_url: ',page_url);

        build_json.items[j] = {};

        var id = $("#xx").val();
        console.log('id: ',id);
        build_json.items[j].id = id;

        build_json.items[j].source_url = page_url;

        var title = $("h1.title").text();
        console.log('title: ',title);
        build_json.items[j].title = title;
    });
});
```

Comment: you should look into Promises

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nodejs Synchronous For each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23693803/nodejs-synchronous-for-each-loop)